# php tag system, get just username from @

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace, message, msg

Right now I have the code:

```
$msgs = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '$1', $msg);
```

Let's say that

```
$msg = "@Admin Hello my friends";
```

The code works above but I need to get just the tagged name! I need to get just "Admin", all the persons who have been tagged. How do I do that?

Comment: The preg_replace code working when I need to make the tagged person to a link.. So that's why I'm using that code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$msgs = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+).*$/', '$1', $msg);
```

or

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', $msg, $match)) {
    $msgs = $match[1];
}
```

If you can have more than one `@` in a single line, use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', $msg, $match)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) But do you know how I can get out all persons who are tag? If i tag two persons maybe? I need that in a "while"/"loop"

Comment: @Johan: I don't get you, do you say there're more than one `@` in a line? Or do you read all from a file? Update your question accordingly with examples.

Comment: $msg = "@Admin @Webmaster Hello!";
Like that! I need to get out Admin and Webmaster.. it's just a string/line

Comment: Thanks! This works well:

preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', $msg, $match);

foreach ($match as $val) {
 $len = count($match);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $test = $val[$i];
echo $test;
    }
}

But it put out the names two times. the first with a @ and then without! I mean: "@Admin Admin"; Two times! Why?

Comment: So if I'm writing @.admin and @.hey it will be "@.admin admin @.hey hey"

Comment: @JohanThat's the way preg_match works, in the first array element you have the whole match and in the second element the first capture group. See the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Ok. How can I do so I just get out without @?

Comment: @Johan: Just take `$val[1]` in your foreach loop.